# Unknown number of iterations to complete the sort

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I am heading towards sorting algorithms. I have just started to learn the Insertion Sort. I needed to make a solution for a already sorted list with an unsorted number at the end. So the problem now is that the loop skips one iteration or adds another duplicate one. Here is what I mean:

When I try to sort this list: `{2, 4, 6, 8 ,3}` I get this:

```
2 4 6 8 3
2 4 6 8 8
2 4 6 6 8
2 4 4 6 8
2 3 4 6 8
2 3 4 6 8 #duplicated! ^
```

And when I try to sort this list: `{2, 4, 6, 8, 1}` I get this:

```
2 4 6 8 8
2 4 6 6 8
2 4 4 6 8
2 2 4 6 8
1 2 4 6 8 #no duplicates
```

How can I know how many iteration do I need to complete the sort? Here's how I sort:

```
ar = list(map(int, input().split()))
mins = ar[-1]
for i in range(len(ar)-1, 0, -1):
    if ar[i-1] > mins: ar[i] = ar[i-1]
    else: ar[i] = mins
    print(*ar)
if mins < ar[0]: ar[0] = mins
print(*ar)
```

Comment: Quick tip: in Python, to get the last element of a list, you can use `ar[-1]` instead of `ar[len(ar)-1]`

Comment: +1 because you asked for an explanation, not just a solution. That is in the spirit of Stack Overflow- your question can now help other people in a more significant way.

Comment: So you give `{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}` but end up with `5 4 3 2 2` - well, *where did the 1 go?* Start there.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui If the *very first operation/cycle* isn't correct, there is not much hope for anything else.

Comment: Aside: since it looks like you're using Python 3, instead of your complicated `print` line you can simply do `print(*ar)`.

Comment: @DSM that looks much slower. :/

Comment: Your approach is O(n) which is not possible for insertion sort.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: it's not.

Comment: Everybody! see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply break the loop when you find `a[i-1] <= mins`.

```
ar = [2, 4, 6, 8 ,1]
mins = ar[-1]
for i in range(len(ar)-1, 0, -1):
    if ar[i-1] > mins: 
        ar[i] = ar[i-1]
    else: 
        ar[i] = mins
        break
    print(ar)
if mins < ar[0]: ar[0] = mins
print(ar)
```

Comment: Actually what I did is that I moved the last print statement inside the body of the last if. That solved it.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui try `ar = [2, 4, 6, 8 ,5]`